# I have Jolteon / Vaporeon / Flareon. I tried for another Jolteon but got a Vaporeon!

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a weak Jolteon, so I took 25 Eevees and tried to evolve another one. I was hoping for stronger combat moves. So, I renamed the Eevee "Sparky" and evolved it, but got a Vaporeon! Losing those 25 candies is really painful. The new Vaporeon has the weakest moves possible. I'm really bummed.

I want to try for a strong Jolteon one more time, but what the heck? Is this a bug? Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nickname trick works only once for each of the Eeveelutions.

Comment: gghhhaaaaaa!!!! what a waste of precious candy.

Comment: The pokégods are just. After a poképarty and an egg hatch, I've got 32 Eevee candies. Unbelievable. Suffice to say, I'm gonna learn to love my Jolteon and power him up.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the Rainer/Sparky/Pyro trick (name your Eevee one of those names to select the corresponding evolutionary track: Vaporean/Joltean/Flareon) works only once for each name.

This seems a reasonable move on Niantic's part, giving players the ability to secure at least one of each type, while having it be a random outcome most of the time, just like hatching an egg - having it permanent would effectively mean *every* evolved Eevee becoming a Vaporean (that seems to the overwhelmingly popular choice).

The Eevee name trick has been called the game's first Easter Egg. The Niantic folk have said as much, and have said there are others no one has found yet, but I don't think they've detailed the precise rules for this Easter Egg's mechanism. Some folks have reported it working multiple times, but remember, you have a one-in-three chance of getting what you wanted anyway - this likely explains occasional reports of repeated success.

The downside is, not knowing this, or missing other bits in the game's learning curve (it outwardly seems simple but there's all sorts of interesting math folks are trying, to get the best possible Pokémons), might mean evolving less powerful/optimal Eevees with one or more of the "single use only" names, and then being sad to find it's not repeatable.

Comment: You are right about everyone uses Vaporeans. But, that is exactly why I wanted a 2nd Jolteon. I've got high cp Lickitung, Vileplume, and Jolteon. If only I had an extra Jolteon to battle the standard fair Vaporean and Gyarados...

Comment: Wow, where do you find Gyarados to be standard fair? I've only seen a couple in Gyms. (75 more damn Magikarp, and one will be mine.)

Comment: 3 Gyarados are bouncing around my local gyms. I often do a 10km run along the shores of 7 different lakes. Yet, I've only 76 Magikarp candies. You hear about GPS spoofing. Almost no one is capable of pulling it off, but maybe 1 guy with 2 friends is in my area.