# What general location gives me the best chance of evolving a Jolteon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've already asked a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280511/i-have-jolteon-vaporeon-flareon-i-tried-for-another-jolteon-but-got-a-vapor). ok, so the naming trick works only once. But, I might give it another try. Here are my facts:

- My first Eevee, not using the naming trick, evolved into Vaporeon.
- Using the naming trick, I later evolved Flareon and Jolteon.
- Not knowing the naming trick works only once, the 4th Eevee I evolved also became a Vaporean.
- I evolved all 4 in my apartment which is surrounded by lakes. The 2 I did not use the naming trick on became Vaporeon.

I read that, naming trick aside, the Flareon / Jolteon / Vaporeon evolution depends on where you do it? Since I was surrounded by water, there was a greater chance than 1/3 of getting a Vaporean each time?

If true, what general location gives me the best chance (but no guarantees) of getting me another Jolteon?

Comment: What makes you think your location makes a difference?

Comment: I don't believe location determines their evolution as I live in the mountains with no bodies of water and 0 water Pokemon anywhere and got 8 Vaporeons in a row.

Comment: @Frank I was just googling around looking for how Eevee evolution works. On some forum, someone with unknown credibility said as such. It gave me hope and matched my experience. At the same time, I don't want to trade 25 Eevees for a 3rd Vaporeon.

Comment: Like you said: Unknown credibility.  Rumors abound; there's little substance to such rumors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Eevee's evolutions (outside of the naming trick, which only work once per evolution) are completely random. During my mass evolutions, I have seen cases where I evolve 2-3 consecutive Jolteon then 3-4 consecutive Flareon in the span of a few minutes. Also, I did not move whilst doing these mass evolutions.

Furthermore, I evolved 2 Flareon before I was able to get any other eeveelutions from evolving, but after that, the next 5 evolutions were Vaporeon.

This would disprove the idea that there is some sort of built-in rotation that other answers have suggested.

To answer your question, though, it does not look like location has any sort of bearing on what eeveelution you are most likely to get.

Comment: agreed. I observed randomness. I did countless Eeveelutions until I got the move-sets that I wanted. I eventually got ideal attack move-sets for Jolteon, Flareon, and Vaporeon. And of course a Vaporeon for defense that has a big hydro-pump.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I observed today.
By chance, I made my first Eeveelution sequence as:
(1) Vaporean
(2) Flareon
(3) Jolteon

As I said in my question, I wanted another Jolteon and used the name trick again. But, I got a Vaporean... because the name trick actually works only once.

In search of a Jolteon, I took risk and continued more Eeveelutions. The sequence repeated itself:
(4) Vaporeon
(5) Flareon
(6) Jolteon

Make of that what you will. Perhaps the initial sequence repeats? Whatever the case, I am not evolving anymore Eevees. I am super happy to have 2 of each.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following renaming trick:

> Those who want a Jolteon should rename their Eevee "Sparky" while those after a Flareon should type "Pyro." Those who want to get Vaporeon should type "Rainer."

[Source](http://christiantimes.com/article/pokemon-go-cheats-tips-eevee-evolution-guide-2016-details-which-eevee-evolution-is-strongest-how-to-force-evolve-eevee/60314.htm)

Its best to restart the app in between naming and evolving to ensure that the nickname saved to the server.

Additionally it seems that you will need to go through one of each of the eeveelutions before you can get a second of the same.

I.e.
You can do:

1. Sparky -> Jolteon
2. Pyro -> Flareon
3. Rainer -> Vaporeon
4. Sparky-> Jolteon

But this will not work:

1. Sparky -> Jolteon
2. Sparky-> Jolteon

The second one will be random because you did not force the other two eeveelutions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the trick itself only works once per type.  Do you have a source for the rotation?

Comment: This is not correct, I evolved two Vaporeons with Eevee named as Rainer without any other Eevee evolution between those.

Comment: the trick only work once to allow you to have all 3 of them but then it is random